# How to set surface+x%primary colors in xml layout

Tags: android, android-layout, colors, material-components

In official Material Design 3 resources do not specify how to use these [(surface+x%primary) colors](https://material.io/blog/tone-based-surface-color-m3) in xml layouts.

I tried using these colors in code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ...
   getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(SurfaceColors.SURFACE_2.getColor(this));
   ...
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've looked up and down, I couldn't see anywhere how you can set surface elevation or set surface colour manually in XML.